# Error saving rules - Line NaN: Ruleset uses old version (version [1]). Please update to the latest version (version [2])

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I get this error in firebase console rules :

> Error saving rules - Line NaN: Ruleset uses old version (version [1]). Please update to the latest version (version [2]).

Then i add this to the top of the rules :

```
rules_version = "2";
service cloud.firestore {
..
```

Then i get a new one :

> Error saving rules - An unknown error occurred

These rules worked before, i didn't even change them, just added a space.

Comment: If you're having problems saving rules in the Firebase console, and the error message isn't helpful, contact Firebase support for assistance. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: thanks i did, its just going to take days which i don't have. Do you know what i can try to do ?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who have so many problems with the rules SDK, most of the times, my solution is to simply delete a lot of older rules ( i had too many rules versions). Firebase console don't know how to tell you about this, only the CLI will.